# How to abort previous execution of an event when it's called again?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, async-await

I know this is probably one I should be able to google easily enough, but just not sure what to search for at the moment...

Basically, I have an event that is raised and while it is still executing it may be raised again. If this happens, I would like to immediately terminate any previous execution.

In this specific case, I'm talking about a SelectionChanged event for a DataGridView. Before I introduced async programming to this project there was no issue. But now I'm finding that as the method waits for results from an async call, it may be raised again. And the new call may finish before the original call which results in an inconsistent UI state.

Comment: Maybe put the Tasks to a queue when SelectionChanged raised?

Comment: Does the async operation accepts a [`CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads)?

Comment: Please, share your code so far

Comment: Is the User not supposed to select anything else while a procedure triggered by `SelectionChanged` is executing? If not, then it's not meant to be async. Do these *selection changes* imply a change in other values of the grid? Or other controls? The data itself? If so, it's probably not meant to be async. Can a User trigger a selection change and/or a change in value of the same element or elements that are/will be affected by the async procedure triggered by `SelectionChange`? If so, not async. What if the Form closes? Would this have consequences on what the async proc is doing?

Comment: If the procedure is triggered by a selection change is meant to change something *somewhere else* (not affecting the current user input) and these changes are also meant to be sequential by their nature/result set, then handle them using a sequential proxy (a queue). Can these procedures be interrupted without causing harm? Then use a CancellationTokenSource to signal the Tasks to exit nicely, knowing that elements in the UI thread that ran them may not be accessible anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    public async void OnMainThread()
    {
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        var newCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cancellationTokenSource = newCts;
        try
        {
            var result = await AsyncOp(newCts.Token);
            if (!newCts.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // Update UI
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // Ignore
        }
    }

    public async Task<int> AsyncOp(CancellationToken cancel)
    {
        // Do the async work
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Very nice! Instead of `if (!newCts.IsCancellationRequested)` you could just call `newCts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();`, which is slightly more succinct.

Comment: This worked... although it's odd the catch block never seems to get hit. Makes me wonder if this change effected it ever so slightly enough to cause it to naturally sequence in the right order.

Comment: Also for any future person reading this thinking the AsyncOp has to take a cancellation token for this to work, I actually didn't update my AsyncOp to take a cancellation token. Mine calls a web service which is going to finish running anyway, but it's not a big deal. Main thing was just to ignore the results.